# What is the phrase when someone is being strict with one side of the dialogue but not the other?

Tags: phrases, expressions

If there's a dialogue between two and the third person who has a bias to one of the opinions constantly asks for proof and being over critical to the other opinion but not the one he believes in it's called what? Something about unequal strictness.

Answer (score 2):

That would be a case of having a **double standard,** defined [by Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20standard) as:

> a set of principles that applies differently and usually more rigorously to one group of people or circumstances than to another